# Efficient way to cbind list by groups in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.frame

**data**

```
data = structure(list(mystring = c("AASDAASADDLKJLKADDLKKLLKJLJADDLJLKJLADLKLADD", 
    "ASDSDFJSKADDKJSJKDFKSADDLKJFLAK"), class = c("cat", "dog")), .Names = c("mystring", 
    "class"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

which looks like

```
#> dtt1
#                                      mystring class
#1 AASDAASADDLKJLKADDLKKLLKJLJADDLJLKJLADLKLADD   cat
#2              ASDSDFJSKADDKJSJKDFKSADDLKJFLAK   dog
```

I am searching the start and end positions of a pattern "ADD" with in the first 20 characters in the strings under `mystring` considering `class` as the group.

I am doing this using `str_locate` of `stringr` package. Here is my attempt

```
setDT(dtt1)[, 
cbind(list(str_locate_all(substr(as.character(mystring), 1, 20),"ADD")[[1]][,1]),
      list(str_locate_all(substr(as.character(mystring), 1, 20),"ADD")[[1]][,2])), 
      by = class]
```

This gives my **desired output**

```
#   class V1 V2
#1:   cat  8 10
#2:   cat 16 18
#3:   dog 10 12
```

**Question**: 
I would like to know if this is a standard approach or this can be done in a more efficient manner. `str_locate` gives the `start` and `end` positions of the matched pattern in separate columns, and I am putting them in separate list to `cbind` them together with the `data.table`? Also how can I specify the `colnames` for the cbinded `columns` here?

Comment: `by=class` is needed?

Comment: @Khashaa yes its in the title of the question. I wanted that by groups

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you first should reduce your operations per group, so I would first create a substring for all groups at once.

```
setDT(data)[, submystring := .Internal(substr(mystring, 1L, 20L))]
```

Then, using the `stringi` package (I don't like wrappers), you could do (though can't currently vouch for efficiency)

```
library(stringi)
data[, data.table(matrix(unlist(stri_locate_all_fixed(submystring, "ADD")), ncol = 2)), by = class]
#    class V1 V2
# 1:   cat  8 10
# 2:   cat 16 18
# 3:   dog 10 12
```

---

Alternatively, you could avoid `matrix` and `data.table` calls per group but spread the data after all the location were detected

```
res <- data[, unlist(stri_locate_all_fixed(submystring, "ADD")), by = class]
res[, `:=`(varnames = rep(c("V1", "V2"), each = .N/2), MatchCount = rep(1:(.N/2), .N/2)), by = class]
dcast(res, class + MatchCount ~ varnames, value.var = "V1")
#    class MatchCount V1 V2
# 1:   cat          1  8 10
# 2:   cat          2 16 18
# 3:   dog          1 10 12
```

---

Third similar option could be to try first run `stri_locate_all_fixed` over the whole data set and only then to `unlist` per group (instead of running both and `unlist` and `stri_locate_all_fixed` per group)

```
res <- data[, .(stri_locate_all_fixed(submystring, "ADD"), class = class)]
res[, N := lengths(V1)/2L]
res2 <- res[, unlist(V1), by = "class,N"]
res2[, `:=`(varnames = rep(c("V1", "V2"), each = N[1L]), MatchCount = rep(1:(N[1L]), N[1L])), by = class]
dcast(res2, class + MatchCount ~ varnames, value.var = "V1")
#    class MatchCount V1 V2
# 1:   cat          1  8 10
# 2:   cat          2 16 18
# 3:   dog          1 10 12
```

Answer (score 4):

We could change the `matrix` output from `str_locate_all` to `data.frame` and use `rbindlist` to create the columns.

```
  setDT(data)[,rbindlist(lapply(str_locate_all(substr(mystring, 1, 20),
               'ADD'), as.data.frame)) , class]
  #   class start end
  #1:   cat     8  10
  #2:   cat    16  18
  #3:   dog    10  12
```

Comment: it worked perfectly fine for my dataset. Although I am using the dcast approach (David's second approach) which I found much faster because of the spiting the tasks in three steps.

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar  No problem.  You should use the one that is efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it.

```
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

data = structure(list(mystring = c("AASDAASADDLKJLKADDLKKLLKJLJADDLJLKJLADLKLADD", 
                                   "ASDSDFJSKADDKJSJKDFKSADDLKJFLAK"), class = c("cat", "dog")), .Names = c("mystring", 
                                                                                                            "class"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")

my_function = function(row)
  row$mystring %>% 
  stri_sub(to = 20) %>%
  stri_locate_all_fixed(pattern = "ADD") %>%
  extract2(1) %>%
  as_data_frame

test = 
  data %>%
  group_by(mystring) %>%
  do(my_function(.)) %>%
  left_join(data)
```